# Want to know the history of item purchased

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Initially I had implemented the code for one time purchase only.

```
        IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);

            // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
            if (mHelper == null) return;

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Error purchasing: " + result);
                return;
            }
            if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
                return;
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");

            if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
                // bought 1/4 tank of gas. So consume it.
                Log.d(TAG, "Purchase is gas. Starting gas consumption.");
                Log.e("Successful","prrrrrrr");
                GlobalClass.savePreferences2("isPremiumUser",1,context);
                mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);
            }
        }
    };
    IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
        public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Consumption finished. Purchase: " + purchase + ", result: " + result);

            // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
            if (mHelper == null) return;

            // We know this is the "gas" sku because it's the only one we consume,
            // so we don't check which sku was consumed. If you have more than one
            // sku, you probably should check...
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // successfully consumed, so we apply the effects of the item in our
                // game world's logic, which in our case means filling the gas tank a bit
                Log.d(TAG, "Consumption successful. Provisioning.");
                Log.e("Consume ","Successful");
                start_Activity();
            }
            else {
                Log.e("Purchase ","failed"+result);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "End consumption flow.");
        }
    };
```

This works only until the user uninstall the app.
Now I want to convert it to one time purchase. I have removed

```
IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener and mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);
```

from my code. It is working fine for the future payments. But I want that the payments made before the changes should also do not require to pay after reinstalling the app. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to create a IAP items that are required to purchase only once, and stored on Google Play's servers, the only thing you need to change is not to consume the item the user has purchased.

So basically just scrape the piece where you call

```
consumeAsync...
```

and instead query the inventory on app startup from Google Plays servers, as of IAP v3 its fast, as the purchases are cached by Google Play.

You can read more about consumable and non-consumables on the [official site](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume).

Only problem you're gonna hit, the users on which behalf you've already consumed the item, will not get it back, for which, you will need to implement something on your own server to handle those cases, or then just make them contact you and manually give them some codes you've implemented to give the feature, but this is really use-case specific choice.